# Поиск спецтегов в html с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите написать регулярное выражение, которое бы искало в заданном HTML-коде спецтеги вида: `[tag_somethingName param1:value param2:value]`, где somethingName может быть любым словом, а количество параметром может быть произвольным.

Comment: В каком месте здесь надо увидеть html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вариант самый простой:

   ```
   $text = <<<END
       Помогите написать регулярное выражение, которое бы искало в заданном 
       HTML-коде спецтеги вида: [tag_somethingName param1:value param2:value], 
       где somethingName может быть любым словом, 
       а количество параметром может быть произвольным.
   END;

   // найти все теги в квадратных скобках
   preg_match_all("/\[(.+?)\]/", $text, $matches);

   foreach ($matches as $tag) {
       // разбиваем найденную строку по пробелу.
       $param = explode(' ', $tag);
       $tagName = array_shift($param);
       // теперь $param содержит массив параметрови со значениями.
       // осталось их разделить тем же `explode(':', $param[0])`
   }
   ```

Comment: 2. Можно поиграться с рекурсивностью в самих регулярках, но я с рекурсией так и не разобрался. Только что попробовал и сел в лужу. Если кто подскажет, сам посмотрю с удовольствием.

Comment: И да, $matches[0] надо пропустить